# Auto-layout constraints for shifting the label down based on upper labels contents

Tags: ios, objective-c, autolayout

I have a cell xib and the labels are listed one below the other. Here is the picture of the cell xib.
[image]

Based on the contents of "Address Details", that particular label will expand and hence, I wish to move down the labels below it which are Contact, contact details, IFSC and MICR related labels.

I did add some constraints to Branch Name label and Address details label. If I set the top space and bottom space constraints priority to 500, then I see the contents of all the labels are messed up. However if I set the priority to 1000, then all the labels look to be in place, but the "Address Details" label doesn't expand based on it's contents.

For expanding the label, I am using

```
label.numberOfLines = 0;
label.text = addressDetails;
[label sizeToFit];
```

***Pic with priority set to 500:***
[image]

***Pic with priority set to 1000:***
[image]

I have never posted here any auto-layout related questions before. I am not sure if the information I posted is sufficient for my question, but any additional info is required, then please let me know.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why do you have the height constraint?  With priority 1000 do you get warnings about conflicting constraints?

Comment: @Paulw11 - I am not getting conflicting constraints with this. I was when it was = 32, so since it can expand, I made it to >= 32.

Comment: What I am saying is you shouldn't have a height constraint at all

Answer (score 0):

You should reset your constraint like this..
`Add Top, Leading and trailing` constraint on `Address Detail Label` and let the `UILabel` to resize them according to content (do not add height constraint).

Now add these constraint to `Address Label` -> (`Top = Address Detail Label Top, Give Height Constraint and Leading and trailing`).

The very next two labels `Contact` and `Contact Detail Label` must be place below `Address detail label` not below `Address Label`.

Now in `heightForRowAtIndexPath` should return `UITableViewAutomaticDimension`.

Now hit the run button and test it if it works for you.

Answer (score 0):

Key is adding bottom constraint to last element in cell and setting estimatedRowHeight to the height of tableviewcell and rowheight to UITableViewAutomaticDimension. No need to set height constraint or implement heightForRowAtIndexPath

For constraints:
 1. First in the tableview cell set the branch label's top, leading and trailing space.
 2. Then align the leading edges of branch, address, contact label.
 3. Then align the trailing edges of branch, address value and contact value label.
 4. Align the leading edges of address value and contact value label.
 5. Then align vertical centers of address and address value. Similarly for contact and contact value.
 6. Then add top space constraint to address value label, and to contact value label.
 7. Add width constrain to address label.
 8. Take a note of the cell height, say its x. Set the table row height to x.

This should complete your general constraints.

Now to have the expanding label:

9. Add bottom constraint to the contact value label(whatever is the bottom most label).
10. Then in viewdidload, set rowheight and estimated row height:

    ```
    self.tableView.estimatedRowHeight = x;
    self.tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension;
    ```

For address value label, set number of lines to 0, and line break to word wrap.
[image]

Comment: For now to make it to work, I updated the priorities to 750 instead of 500 or 1000 and that helped. I will give this a try and will let you know. Thanks!